# Very abnormal beahavior when launching roscore

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS melodic directly on my PC ( no dockers )

At start up, when i open a new shell to start Roscore i have a **gohst roscore** arready running

i have an error telling me that roscore is already running??

If i type:  `rostopic list`, i have a long list of topics displayed even if nothing was launched ???

I have tried many things to solve the problem:

- I have rebooted the pc a few times ( it does not change any things )
- I have tried to kill the roscore node but the program process is not apearing in the list of the system monitor?

Finnaly i have been able to find the process with ps aux | grep roscore

```
ros       1922  0.6  0.3 327480 56288 ?        Ssl  21:32   0:00 /usr/bin/python /opt/ros/melodic/bin/roscore
francois  3990  0.0  0.0  14732  1052 pts/0    S+   21:33   0:00 grep --color=auto roscore
```

I had to use sudo kill 1922 because i was not the owner of the process.

**Unfortunately every time i reboot the gohst roscore is back**

At first, i tough that it was related to the last activities made in the PC.

I had purged then resinsalled the ros flexbe package

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
....
sudo apt install ros-$ROS_DISTRO-flexbe-behavior-engine
```

It seems that the problem is not related to the upgrade and install done in the previous step.

- I have not been using ros locally since 1 week or 2
- I have used timeshift to restore a version 2 day old version and the problem remains ???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350043/very-abnormal-beahavior-when-launching-roscore/) by [frge](https://answers.ros.org/users/53783/frge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2020-04-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-21**:
It would perhaps be good to add more information here.

> After an ubuntu udate and upgrade to install a new package

"an update" and "a new package" is too vague. Please try to be specific.

> At start up, when i open a new shell to start Roscore i have an error telling me that roscore is already running?

`roscore` does not start itself, so something must be starting it. Does this `roscore` instance persist across reboots? If it does: do you happen to be using Docker? No persistent/auto-restarting containers?

**Comment by [frge](https://answers.ros.org/users/53783/frge/) on 2020-04-21**:
I Have added info in the original description of the problem

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-21**:
Could you show the output of `env | grep -i ros | sort`? We need to make sure it's actually a local `roscore`.

Can you kill the running `roscore`? Does it stay shutdown, or immediately startup again?

Have you used something like [robot_upstart](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_upstart)?

**Comment by [frge](https://answers.ros.org/users/53783/frge/) on 2020-04-21**:
Here is the result of the questions Part 1
Can you kill the running roscore? Does it stay shutdown, or immediately startup again?

```
  Not able to kill it ( like a phantom roscore)
        1) Not listed in System monitor

        2) in a shell
            kill roscore
            bash: kill: roscore: arguments must be process or job IDs
```

Have you used something like robot_upstart? No, and this package is not installed
roscd robot_upstart
roscd: No such package/stack 'robot_upstart'

**Comment by [frge](https://answers.ros.org/users/53783/frge/) on 2020-04-21**:
Part 2a
env | grep -i ros | sort
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/francois/catkin_ws/devel:/opt/ros/melodic
EUSDIR=/opt/ros/melodic/share/euslisp/jskeus/eus/
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/melodic/share/euslisp/jskeus/eus//Linux64/lib:/home/francois/catkin_ws/devel/lib:/opt/ros/melodic/lib:/usr/local.1/cuda-10/lib64:/opt/ros/melodic/share/euslisp/jskeus/eus//Linux64/lib
PATH=/opt/ros/melodic/share/euslisp/jskeus/eus//Linux64/bin:/opt/ros/melodic/bin:/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin:/opt/ros/melodic/share/euslisp/jskeus/eus//Linux64/bin:/home/francois/bin:/home/francois/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/francois/catkin_ws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/melodic/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig

**Comment by [frge](https://answers.ros.org/users/53783/frge/) on 2020-04-21**:
Part 2 b
PYTHONPATH=/home/francois/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so
ROS_DISTRO=melodic
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/melodic/etc/ros
ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.2.18
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/francois/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/francois/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/melodic/share
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=2
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS_VERSION=1

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-21**:
Please add this sort of info to your original post. Use the `edit` button/link for that. Comments are unsuited.

**Comment by [frge](https://answers.ros.org/users/53783/frge/) on 2020-04-21**:
The problem description has been edited

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-22**:
Where is the `env` output in your question text? I cannot find it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-22**:
*Something* is starting that `roscore`. Seeing as you write this:

> I had to use sudo kill 1922 because i was not the owner of the process.

it sounds like a system service is starting it.

I would recommend to take a look at the contents of `/etc/init.d` or any of the other directories and configuration files which are involved in auto-starting processes on Ubuntu Xenial.

`roscore` does not auto-start. It will have to be some form of automation starting a `.launch` file or similar.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-22**:
And probably unrelated, but:

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/francois/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so
```

this does not make sense to me: note how this contains both `kinetic` *and* `melodic` paths. That cannot be right.

Additionally:

```
ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.2.18
```

do *not* set `ROS_HOSTNAME` to an IP. Use `ROS_IP` for that. Or configure `ROS_HOSTNAME` with a hostname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have solved the problem.

This problem seem to have generated by the installation of binary package of the fecth robot a few days ago.

I have removed the roscore.service related files ans directory in
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/roscore.service
/home/francois/roscore.service.wants

---

Originally posted by [frge](https://answers.ros.org/users/53783/frge/) with karma: 51 on 2020-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0